# Help the Monkee get to the bandanas

Tags: mazes, cryptic-crosswords

**Micky Dolenz**, drummer and vocalist of 1960s pop band The Monkees, has lost his headwear collection. It has been hidden in a maze whose walls are in unknown places. To find out the location of the walls, solve the cryptic clues and place the solutions in the maze. Can you help the Monkee get to the bandanas?

> [image]

Rules/clarifications:

> - Word boundaries indicate walls.
> - Every square is reachable from the start. (You'll likely need this information when solving the maze.)
> - Some clues are missing the answer of another clue.

**Across**

> 1. Permission to infuriate, losing nation's {*5d*} associated with the left (7)
> 2. Pilgrim shakes head, joins {*3d*} to abstain from participating (7)
> 3. Orbit around vandalized totem symbol of South {*10d*} (8)
> 4. Important organ to {*2a*} keynote, leading to a tangle (4)
> 5. Spin single going {*13d*} behind central clubhouse (7)
> 6. Losing final argument, chauvinist {*4d*} numbers (5)
> 7. Extremely common containers, primarily metal (4)
> 8. Wash and finally brush a mop color, alternately (7)
> 9. Spiritual leaders siege America for food items (8)
> 10. High time for antivirus to block the middleman (4)
> 11. Assessment for former Vietnam right-wingers (4)
> 12. Newly have confidence in acquired currency (8)
> 13. {*7d*} degree to cause misery to African city (7)
> 14. Fruit wines central in cooked apple pie (9)
> 15. In need of carving at {*6a*} and sevens (7)
> 16. {*15a*} a cleanup, forget pressing start (4)

**Down**

> 1. Oral tradition expressed by people with a strange role (8)
> 2. Leading activists {*12a*} sheltering seabird by turns (11)
> 3. High-ranking Mormon abruptly stern to child (9)
> 4. Turned to reject without first sign of reason (4)
> 5. Leading explosive ignores military conflict (4)
> 6. Christmas novel {*7a*} virgin's introduction (4)
> 7. Bones's {*9d*} function in USS enterprise (8)
> 8. Deception extremely hateful, trees said (4)
> 9. Authentic {*12d*} transfer final, not initial (8)
> 10. Panthers' home is in a {*6d*} at the top (8)
> 11. Sea cows have tea, eat lost insects (6)
> 12. Support softcover lacking material (4)
> 13. First biological genus of {*14a*} fruits (7)
> 14. Mother leaves fresh {*11d*} home (4)
> 15. Way to touch honest leader (4)
> 16. City with a rag in a {*4a*} (4)
> 17. {*8d*} writing framework (7)

---

<sub>Central image credit: Steven Depolo, CC BY 2.0</sub>

Comment: I’m a believer in your puzzle-making skill!

Comment: 12a  I think IN and ACQUIRED are conflicting.

Comment: FWIW I think 12a is OK.

Comment: I suppose you could take it as the phrase "Have confidence in" but the word that keys to is often followed by "on"  So I'd say IN should go.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that in the maze, no words overlap with each other in the same direction, only between across and down words? e.g. ARMORDER has overlapping OR between ARMOR and ORDER.

Comment: @ZanyG Yes, no overlaps in the same direction. Also, each across clue overlaps with at least one down clue (and vice versa).

Comment: Should the enumeration to 7d be (8) rather than (9)?

Comment: @MOehm Oops, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: Are the words in grid  all left to right or top down?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Partial answer** to some clues.

9d.

> Authentic {12d:BACK} transfer final, not initial (8)
>  ORIGINAL - GIRO< + (f)INAL

7d.

> Bones's {9d:ORIGINAL} function in USS enterprise (9)
>  BUSINESS - B(ones) + SINE in USS

13a.

> {7d:BUSINESS} degree to cause misery to African city (7)
>  MBABANE (capital of Eswanti / Swaziland) - MBA + BANE

16a.

> {15a:CRAVING} a cleanup, forget pressing start (4)
>  URGE - (p)URGE (cleanup - P(ressing))

**Final maze**.   Gareth and Chris have filled in most of the answers, so credit to them. The final maze looks like this:

> [image: Maze]

Comment: Everything's correct except 8d (Chris Cudmore's answer is correct there). Between the three of you you have everything except 7a.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes better sense. (I hadn't looked at Chris's answer.)

Comment: Alright, I'm peaking.  9D is absolutely impossible for a Non-European to figure out.

Comment: We like to have our little niches of secret Old World knowledge ... `;)`

Comment: I'm not seeing any easter eggs in that.  Usually @jafe puts in a hidden theme or something.  Unless it's the complete absence of the letter D, which means the Monkee is actually going to the Bananas.

Comment: The letters along the path anagram to the chorus of "I'm a Believer", obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Partial 
If I could do inline spoilers, I'd inline the substitutions.

**Across**

1 Permission to infuriate, losing nation's {5d} associated with the left (7)
2 Pilgrim shakes head, joins {3d} to abstain from participating (7)

> **BOY +** s**COTT** pilgrim (comic book character)

3 Orbit around vandalized totem symbol of South {10d} (8)

> ! **PALMETTO** not entirely parsed, but LAP + TOTEM all anagrammed up.

4 Important organ to {2a} keynote, leading to a tangle (4)

> **K**ey**NOT**e  (EYE boycotts KEYNOTE)

5 Spin single going {13d} behind central clubhouse (7)

> **ENGLISH** anagram of single + h

6 Losing final argument, chauvinist {4d} numbers (5)

> **SIXES**  SEXIST - T (Final argument) So 4D must mean back or reverse

7 Extremely common containers, primarily metal (4)
8 Wash and finally brush a mop color, alternately (7)

> bru**SH A M ** o **P** c **O** l **O** r

9 Spiritual leaders siege America for food items (8)
10 High time for antivirus to block the middleman (4)

> **NO** rt **ON**  (not fully parsed but a good guess)

11 Assessment for former Vietnam right-wingers (4)
12 Newly have confidence in acquired currency (8)

> **RE(CENT)LY**

13 {7d} degree to cause misery to African city (7)
14 Fruit wines central in cooked apple pie (9)

> **PINEAPPLE** Wines central is N

15 In need of carving at {6a} and sevens (7)

> **CRAVING** (anagram of carving - "At Sixes and Sevens" means confused)

16 {15a} a cleanup, forget pressing start (4)

**Down**

1 Oral tradition expressed by people with a strange role (8)

> **FOLK+LORE**

2 Leading activists {12a} sheltering seabird by turns (11)

> **A+L(TERN)ATELY**

3 High-ranking Mormon abruptly stern to child (9)

> brigham **YOUNG + STER**n

4 Turned to reject without first sign of reason (4)
5 Leading explosive ignores military conflict (4)
6 Christmas novel {7a} virgin's introduction (4)
7 Bones's {9d} function in USS enterprise (9)
8 Deception extremely hateful, trees said (4)

> **H + OAX** ... extremely **H**ateful + Homophone of OAKS

9 Authentic {12d} transfer final, not initial (8)
10 Panthers' home is in a {6d} at the top (8)

> **CAROL + IN A** not fully parsed still need 6d but this goes wihh 3a

11 Sea cows have tea, eat lost insects (6)

> **MANTES**  (MANATEES - "EAT"  insert a T (for TEA)  Plural of MANTIS

12 Support softcover lacking material (4)

> paper**BACK**

13 First biological genus of {14a} fruits (7)

> **B+ANANAS**

14 Mother leaves fresh {11d} home (4)

> **NEST**  MANTES - MA, fresh (anagram)

15 Way to touch honest leader (4)

> **PAT + H**onest

16 City with a rag in a {4a} (4)

> **AGRA** (A RAG in a knot)

17 {8d} writing framework (7)

> **CON + TEXT**

Comment: All correct so far!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

OK, so I've abandoned my pride and filled my gaps with others' answers; we now have everything except for 7a. The *across* answers are:

> LICENSE BOYCOTT PALMETTO KNOT ENGLISH SIXES [*7a goes here*] SHAMPOO SAUSAGES
>  NOON EXAM RECENTLY MBABANE PINEAPPLE CRAVING URGE

and the *down* answers are:

> FOLKLORE ALTERNATELY YOUNGSTER SPUN HEAD NOEL BUSINESS HOAX
>  ORIGINAL CAROLINA MANTES BACK BANANAS NEST PATH AGRA CONTEXT

(I still don't quite understand 5d, but no one else has anything different and I think jafe has said that we have everything except 7a, so it must be right...)

Now, an observation that may (but probably doesn't) help us figure out something about the mysterious 7a.

> Look at that Y near the top right. It has to be part of an *across* answer. The existing ones with Y in are BOYCOTT and RECENTLY. It can't be part of BOYCOTT because there isn't enough space to its right. If it's part of RECENTLY then the R is (at present) at the end of a *down* space, but there are no *down* answers ending in R. So either (1) that Y is the end of RECENTLY and there's a wall above the R at the start of that word, or (2) the Y is part of the answer to 7a. (Is there some way to make 7a be VERY? That does mean "extremely", and ends in Y, but nothing else about it seems to work.) I think option 1 is more likely.

Explanations for the answers I got:

> 1a. Permission to infuriate, losing nation's {5d:HEAD?} associated with the left (7)
>
>  LICENSE: INCENSE-N after L
>
>        2a. Pilgrim shakes head, joins {3d:YOUNGSTER} to abstain from participating (7)
>
>  BOYCOTT: BOY + (s)COTT
>
>        3a. Orbit around vandalized totem symbol of South {10d:CAROLINA} (8)
>
>  PALMETTO: LAP< + TOTEM*
>
>        4a. Important organ to {2a:BOYCOTT} keynote, leading to a tangle (4)
>
>  KNOT: K(ey)NOT(e)
>
>        5a. Spin single going {13d:BANANAS} behind central clubhouse (7)
>
>  ENGLISH: SINGLE* after (club)H(ouse)
>
>        6a. Losing final argument, chauvinist {4d:SPUN} numbers (5)
>
>  SIXES: SEXIS(t)<
>
>        7a. Extremely common containers, primarily metal (4)
>        8a. Wash and finally brush a mop color, alternately (7)
>
>  SHAMPOO: (bru)SH + A + M(o)P(c)O(l)O(r)
>
>        9a. Spiritual leaders siege America for food items (8)
>
>  SAUSAGES: SAGES around USA
>
>       10a. High time for antivirus to block the middleman (4)
>
>  NOON: NO(rt)ON ???
>
>       11a. Assessment for former Vietnam right-wingers (4)
>
>  EXAM: EX+(vietn)AM
>
>       12a. Newly have confidence in acquired currency (8)
>
>  RECENTLY: RELY contains ("acquired") CENT
>
>       13a. {7d} degree to cause misery to African city (7)
>       14a. Fruit wines central in cooked apple pie (9)
>
>  PINEAPPLE: anag of (wi)N(es)+APPLEPIE
>
>       15a. In need of carving at {6a:SIXES} and sevens (7)
>
>  CRAVING: CARVING*
>
>       16a. {15a:CRAVING} a cleanup, forget pressing start (4)
>        1d. Oral tradition expressed by people with a strange role (8)
>
>  FOLKLORE: FOLK+ROLE*
>
>        2d. Leading activists {12a:RECENTLY} sheltering seabird by turns (11)
>
>  ALTERNATELY: A+LATELY shelters TERN
>
>        3d. High-ranking Mormon abruptly stern to child (9)
>
>  YOUNGSTER: (Brigham) YOUNG + STER(n)
>
>        4d. Turned to reject without first sign of reason (4)
>
>  SPUN: SPURN-R(eason)
>
>        5d. Leading explosive ignores military conflict (4)
>
>  HEAD? (HE=explosive, but what then?)
>
>        6d. Christmas novel {7a:ZINC?} virgin's introduction (4)
>
>  NOEL: NOVEL-V(irgin); 7a might mean "before" or "without"
>
>        7d. Bones's {9d} function in USS enterprise (9)
>        8d. Deception extremely hateful, trees said (4)
>        9d. Authentic {12d:BACK} transfer final, not initial (8)
>       10d. Panthers' home is in a {6d:NOEL} at the top (8)
>
>  CAROLINA: IN A preceded by CAROL
>
>       11d. Sea cows have tea, eat lost insects (6)
>       12d. Support softcover lacking material (4)
>
>  BACK: PAPERBACK-PAPER
>
>       13d. First biological genus of {14a} fruits (7)
>
>  BANANAS: B+ANANAS
>
>       14d. Mother leaves fresh {11d} home (4)
>       15d. Way to touch honest leader (4)
>
>  PATH: PAT+H(onest)
>
>       16d. City with a rag in a {4a:KNOT} (4)
>
>  AGRA: ARAG*
>
>       17d. {8d} writing framework (7)

Comment: @jafe Would you care to comment on whether my 7a is right? I strongly suspect it isn't.

Comment: 7a is not correct.

Comment: Btw, everything's been found except 7a. Just noting in case you want to peek at other answers :)

Comment: A long shot at 7a might be rot13(FNAf = fgbentr nern argjbexf, fnaf = jvgubhg) but I wouldn't say they are common outside of IT, but they are primarily metal.

Comment: I did wonder about that answer, which would be good for 6d, but couldn't see any good way to justify it. Yours, while ingenious, doesn't convince me :-).

Comment: I'm playing with Rot13(pnaf)  Which would also work for 6d, But I can't fully parse it.  I might be distracted by the surface reading.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: Wouldn't rot13(GVAF) be better, given the last part? Anyway, my maze layout wants the word to be --N-.

Comment: Chris's answer works for 6d but yours doesn't.

Comment: @MOehm  I've been playing with that as well.   but Extremely Common hints at the other option.

Comment: I don't see how either works, sorry. Forget about my comment.

Comment: Could Chris's 7a rot13(pnaf) be read as an &lit: Ca(lcium) <primarily metal - meaning put first> +ns <Extremely common containers>?

Comment: Ah, that's pretty plausible.

Comment: 5d has already been confirmed, but I think the wordplay is based on "warhead".

Comment: Oh, of course! Must be right.